# What happens when User's UPN Suffix is not Trusted in Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell-v3.0, active-directory

I have 1275 UPN Suffix in the AD. This is the maximum allowed in Windows Server 2012.

```
$domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain();
$domaindn = ($domain.GetDirectoryEntry()).distinguishedName;
$upnDN = "cn=partitions,cn=configuration,$domaindn";
```

When I create a user using ADAC interface I cannot select an UPN with an UPN Suffix that is not listed in the ADDT UPN Suffixes.

I can however create an user using PowerShell with any UPN Suffix.

```
$userDN = "cn=Users,$domaindn";
$userLogin = "user@foobar.com";
New-ADUser -AccountPassword  (Read-Host -AsSecureString "Insert $userLogin Account Password") -DisplayName "" -EmailAddress $userLogin -Enabled $true -Name $userLogin -Path $userDN -PasswordNeverExpires $true -SAMAccountName $userLogin -UserPrincipalName $userLogin
```

This does not add the UPN Suffix as AD trusted. As far as I have tested, the user works fine.

- What are the ill effects that might come from having a user created with an UPN which UPN Suffix is not listed in the AD Trusted UPN Suffix list?

Comment: You have **one thousand two hundred and seventy five** UPN suffixes in your environment? Can you explain why? I'm very curious.

Comment: Cutting a long story short, the applications use the Active Directory to store the users credentials with an email format. All clients have to register with a valid client company email. This email is used as the upn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the "trusted UPN list" is just what populates the dialog box when creating a new user. There are no problems with users created using any UPN via PowerShell or another API.

As far as I can remember from my days with HMC/MPS, any custom UPN (each customer would have one or multiple unique UPNs) were *never* added to the "UPN list", which should go to show that it is supported creating users with "non-trusted" UPNs.